# scala - add sequence number to xml element

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

I have an XML as a NodeSeq. I am looking for an option to traverse the tags inside the xml and assign a sequence number to each tag.

For example, consider the below XML is available as a Node Seq. I need to add an attribute SeqNum and assign a sequence number value for each of the tags in a List of tags {Employee, name, age}.

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <name>Name1</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <Remarks>xxxx</Remarks>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>Name1</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <Remarks>xxxx</Remarks>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

The output xml should be as below:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee SeqNum="001001">
        <name SeqNum="001002">Name1</name>
        <age SeqNum="001003">30</age>
        <Remarks>xxxx</Remarks>
    </Employee>
    <Employee SeqNum="002001">
        <name SeqNum="002002">Name1</name>
        <age SeqNum="002003">30</age>
        <Remarks>xxxx</Remarks>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Please share your suggestion to achieve this in scala.